# Using the Meteor.settings feature

Tags: javascript, settings, meteor

Meteor recently added a brand new [Meteor.settings](http://docs.meteor.com/meteor_settings#meteor_settings) object starting v0.5.4. And in an extremely annoying manner, didn't properly explain, with example, in their documentation how to setup settings.

In my app, I have a text file (in the root) called "settings.json":

```
{
    "initURL" : "http://localhost:60326/"
}
```

But when I try to start the app using `meteor --settings settings.json`, I get the following error:

```
undefined:1
∩╗┐{
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ∩╗┐
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.exports.getSettings (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\meteor\run.
js:537:10)
    at start_server (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\meteor\run.js:239:28)
    at exports.run.restart_server (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\meteor\run.
js:655:21)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\meteor\run.js:726:9
    at Socket.exports.launch_mongo (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\lib\mongo_
runner.js:187:9)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:391:31)
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong with my Meteor app's settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have hidden characters in your `settings.json`, probably due to a copy-paste.

Your best bet is to delete the file and write it manually, or to get a text editor that can view all these unicode characters and remove them.

Comment: Nope. That is what I suspected initially, but I confirmed the non presence of any bad characters by opening the file in Notepad, Notepad++ and Visual Studio.

Comment: Hmm... nevermind. I deleted the old file and recreated it using Windows Explorer. Guess what? It worked!

Turns out Visual Studio wrongly created a text file last time :p

Comment: It is probably a UTF byte order mark. Notepad, Notepad++ and Visual Studio support them, Meteor apparently doesn't.

Comment: You can fix these in Notepad++ by selecting "Encoding"/"Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" from the menu.

Comment: I'm getting `parse error reading settings file` when I run my code. My settings file is simply `{'a': 'b'}` (for testing) and it's written using emacs. Thoughs?