# Meteor.js spiderable nothing in body tag

Tags: seo, meteor, phantomjs

I'm having a problem indexing my static html page done with meteor.js

I've added the spiderable package, phantomjs to my server $PATH. The spiderable package adds the `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

If i do a `curl` i dont get anything returned in the body tags.

site is hosted on stackful.io : Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with Nginx

Webmaster Tools returns indexed pages (from head) but does not detect any structured data on the site

Comment: If you run curl is there a noticeable pause (like a timeout) before the html is returned?

Comment: @alanning yes there is kind of like a timeout issue. i do curl, it stalls for a bit and then returns empty body tags.

Comment: Update : actually the issue only happens on my remote server, on localhost it returns the data properly! any help apreciated :)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem getting spiderable to work behind an nginx server. It looks like nginx does not support websocket connections. I found these two resources, but am not familiar enough with how nginx works to understand them:

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sockjs/-B7nma72kBA

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Answer (score 1):

Spiderable and nginx don't like to play nicely for some reason having to do with the websocket connection requested. I ended up using the settings object in Meteor to connect directly to my app via a custom port. See [Using the Meteor.settings feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433254/using-the-meteor-settings-feature) for more information. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: `initURL` isn't a documented config setting. Can you explain where you found that?

Comment: I'm not sure....I tried it same as what was listed by the individual who asked the question linked above, and it started serving the html to my site. Someone else pointed out that initURL isn't a config setting as well, so I'm not exactly sure why my page is loading html for search engines now :-/

Answer (score 0):

Spiderable is particularly sensitive to the way your published subscriptions work.  Internally, spiderable will [wait until all subscriptions are in their 'ready' state](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spiderable/spiderable.js#L54), but there's also a [timeout](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spiderable/spiderable.js#L84) to make sure it doesn't just sit there forever.

From what you are describing, it sounds like one of your subscriptions is not returning 'ready' before the timeout expires.

I had the same problem when I was making [meteor-roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles).  To fix this, look through all of your publish functions and make sure that they all either return a cursor, call this.ready, this.error, or this.stop.